Testing a library with a #if NET_STANDARD_2_1 directive
I have a library that targets multiple frameworks, one of which is .Net 8 and one of which is .Net Standard 2.1. Some functions aren't included in the older framework, so I write my own version for it. In this case consider this code:
public static class RandomExtensions
{
#if NETSTANDARD2_1_OR_GREATER
    public static long NextInt64(this Random random) => // my implementation.
#endif
}

I have a test project (xUnit) targeting .Net 8 with the following test:
// Ignore for now that this is a silly test...
public class RandomExtensionsTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void NextInt64()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var value = random.NextInt64();
        Assert.InRange(value, 0, long.MaxValue - 1);
    }
}

When I run this code, it obviously targets the .Net 8 implementation. How can I make it target my implementation instead?
My thinking was that I could target the same frameworks in my test project as in my library project, however you cannot target .Net standard in a test project since it is not a platform (see here). So I tried targeting .Net core app 2.1, but then when I try to reference my library I get the warning Project xxx is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1. I'm at a bit of a loss here with what's left to do.

Let me stress that I cannot target a different framework in my library. It has to target .Net Standard 2.1 since I'm trying to make this package compatible with Unity, as well as ensure that the code carries over to .Net 8 when Unity (finally) switches.

I've made a bit of a blunder... I assumed .Net Standard 2.1 would be compatible with .Net Core 2.1 purely based on versioning. This page shows compatible platforms.
After targeting netcoreapp3.1 everything worked, the test project now targets my .Net Standard 2.1 implementation as expected.

You don't need to target a legacy framework to do this - you can call your method from your .NET 8 tests - see my answer.

That doesn't work, the .Net 8 version of my test project references the .Net 8 version of my library, which means the directive is not respected. Either way, it is better to target the legacy framework for my purposes, since I need to test my library on this legacy framework. But a smart and creative answer nonetheless!

I'm surprised that netcoreapp3.1 doesn't have the same problem as net8. Will have to research that some more...

Ah, I get it now - it's not that netcoreapp3.1 defines NETSTANDARD2_1_OR_GREATER, it's that when you use netcoreapp3.1 it depends on the netstandard2.1 version of the library. Doh. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I think there is some way of forcing a particular version of a dependency, but what you've got is probably a simpler approach.
